# Please, help to find the area enclosed by the curves: ContourPlot[{x + y^2 == 0, x + 3 y^2 - 2 == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Please, Help to find the area between two curves.

```
ContourPlot[{x + y^2 == 0, x + 3 y^2 - 2 == 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica!   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You need to know how to integrate ...

Answer (score 5):

```
Area@ImplicitRegion[x + y^2 >= 0 && x + 3 y^2 - 2 <= 0, {x, y}]
(* 8/3 *)
```

or

```
rgn = DiscretizeRegion@ImplicitRegion[x + y^2 >= 0 && x + 3 y^2 - 2 <= 0, {x, y}];
Area[rgn]
(* 2.66664 *)
```

or

```
eqs = {x + 3 y^2 - 2 == 0, x + y^2 == 0};
xs = First@Solve[#, x] & /@ eqs;
pts = Solve[Reverse@eqs, {x, y}];
NIntegrate[Subtract @@ (x /. xs), Evaluate@{y, Sequence @@ (y /. pts)}]
(* 2.66667 *)
```

or do it by hand.

Comment: Thank you very much! Its really good.

Answer (score 3):

The area you are looking for is enclosed by the curves

```
x == -y^2
x == -3 y^2 + 2
```

They intersect here:

```
Solve[-y^2 == -3 y^2 + 2, y]
(* {{y -> -1}, {y -> 1}} *)
```

Plotting the area of interest:

```
Plot[{-y^2, -3 y^2 + 2}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see the area between the curves is simply the difference between areas under each individual curves:

```
Integrate[-3 y^2 + 2 - (-y^2), {y, -1, 1}]
(* 8/3 *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It really worked for me.